# Prevent NaN to become index and column in dataframe pivot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a dataframe which I extend to include values for all increments in 2 columns. Therefor NaN values are introduced, as expected and desired.

However, when I use pivot on this dataframe I'll get a row and column for NaN. 
Can I prevent this when doing the pivot? If not, how can I drop a column named NaN? 
Trying to drop it by calling [NaN],[nan] or ['NaN'] doesn't work.

Dropping the columns and rows where all values are NaN is not working in this case as the column headings and indexes are used for a seaborn heatmap plot, so eventhough all cell values are NaN it is still useful to have it as the index and key values are not NaN

Sample code;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#generate dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Y': np.random.randint(130,140,10),
                   'X': np.random.randint(5,10,10),
                   'Z': np.random.randint(0,25, size=10)})
df = df.round(1)
#create dataset for heatmap
#group by axis to plot
df = df.groupby(['X','Y']).sum().reset_index()
df = df.sort_values(by=['Y'])
dfY = pd.DataFrame({'Y':np.arange(min(df['Y']), max(df['Y']),1)})
dfX = pd.DataFrame({'X':np.arange(min(df['X']), max(df['X']),1)})
df = pd.merge(df,dfY, how='outer', on='Y')
df = pd.merge(df,dfX, how='outer', on='X')
df = df.round(1)

print(df)
#restructure for heatmap
data = df.pivot("Y","X","Z").sort_values(by=['Y'],ascending=False)
print(data)
```

Sample DataFrame before pivot:

```
      X      Y     Z
0   5.0  132.0   0.0
1   5.0  135.0  20.0
2   5.0  137.0  17.0
3   7.0  132.0  15.0
4   7.0  133.0   3.0
5   6.0  133.0  30.0
6   6.0  135.0  22.0
7   6.0  138.0  16.0
8   9.0  135.0   9.0
9   NaN  134.0   NaN
10  NaN  136.0   NaN
11  8.0    NaN   NaN
```

After pivot:

```
X       NaN    5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0
Y                                         
 138.0   NaN   NaN  16.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
 137.0   NaN  17.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 136.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 135.0   NaN  20.0  22.0   NaN   NaN   9.0
 134.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 133.0   NaN   NaN  30.0   3.0   NaN   NaN
 132.0   NaN   0.0   NaN  15.0   NaN   NaN
NaN      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Desired output:

```
X        5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0
Y                                         
 138.0   NaN  16.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
 137.0  17.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 136.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 135.0  20.0  22.0   NaN   NaN   9.0
 134.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 133.0   NaN  30.0   3.0   NaN   NaN
 132.0   0.0   NaN  15.0   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me working [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) by missing value `np.nan`:

```
data = (df.pivot("Y","X","Z")
         .sort_values(by=['Y'],ascending=False)
         .drop(np.nan, axis=1)
         .drop(np.nan))
```

Or:

```
data = df.pivot("Y","X","Z").sort_values(by=['Y'],ascending=False)

data = data.reindex(index=data.index.difference([np.nan]),
                    columns=data.columns.difference([np.nan]))
```

Comment: excellent, np.nan is the solution for the drop. Adding a drop for axis=0 as well get's me the desired output